# Java Hashmap like data structure that locks the key-value pair on get and unlocks back on put - for crawler politeness

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, web-crawler

**Original Problem**: I have a multithreaded crawler application. In this I need to ensure that the target servers are not flooded with requests. So in order to accomplish that I need to ensure consecutive requests to the particular domain is happening with certain interval(say 200ms).

**My Solution**: As a naive solution to this problem I thought of maintaining a map of domain name to last requested time. And if a new request to certain domain is to be given, I'll check for the last requested time from the map and delay the request by the necessary time to ensure the interval is maintained between requests.

**Flaw in current Solution and the fix**: But this naive fix will fail if two or more threads request same primary domian at a given point of time. Because all threads will sleep till the interval and give the request at the same time, that will make the target server get flooded with requests.
Fix: The fix I am thinking of is to lock the key of the map on get, so all other threads will wait and unlock on put, so next waiting thread can continue.
Is it the correct way to approach the problem? If so, do we have any map data structure implemented like this?
Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple adaption to the map approach to solve your problem. First, I show some code, and I will explain it afterwards:

```
class Scheduler {
    private final Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final long interval = 200; // ms
    public void sleepAsLongAsNecessary(String key) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deadline = next(now, key);
        while (now < deadline) {
            Thread.sleep(deadline - now);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    private synchronized long next(long now, String key) {
        Long oldValue = map.get(key);
        long newValue = oldValue == null ? now : Math.max(oldValue + interval, now);
        map.put(key, newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

This looks pretty similar to the solution you described. The important difference is:

The map does not store the last request time. Instead, it stores the planned request time of the last thread, that asked for a request time. If several threads ask for a request time at the same time, each of them will get a different planned request time.

As soon as the threads knows its planned request time, it will sleep as long as necessary.

Comment: you would need to acquire a lock on key inside the while loop, otherwise can two threads not enter the while loop at the same time?

Comment: @brainstorm: The method `next` is locked. There is no need to lock anything else. Each thread gets its own deadline, and will wait until the deadline is reached - independent of all other threads.

Comment: I see next method is locked, but it doesn't delay interval time. it returns the value and lock is released. but Thread.sleep happens in while loop, during which other threads can enter the while loop and go to sleep state correct?

Comment: @brainstorm: The first thread enters the method at time `t0`, it finds no entry in the map, it adds an entry with `t0`, and it will not sleep. The second thread enters the method at time `t0 + 42`, if finds an entry in the map with time `t0`, it puts an entry into the map with `t0 + 200`, it will sleep until `t0 + 200` (i.e. 158 ms). The third thread enters the method at time `t0 + 84`, if finds an entry in the map with time `t0 + 200`, it puts an entry with `t0 + 400`, it will sleep until `t0 + 400` (i.e. 316 ms). I can't see the problem.

Comment: I understand now. one question though what happens when two threads enter at t0+42? both will be put to sleep but both will get to running state at same instance?

Comment: @brainstorm: The method `next` is synchronized, that means it will be executed sequentially. One of the threads will enter the method first, and it will update the entry to `t0 + 200` and sleep until `t0 + 200`. The other thread will update the entry to `t0 + 400` and sleep until `t0 + 400`. You seem to be confused about the local variables `now` and `deadline`, but these variables are specific to each thread, and have no impact on each other.

Comment: @nosid But making next method synchronized is going to be unnecessary, no? As it will be locked irrespective of domain name? Shouldn't we be synchronizing on the domain name?

Comment: @vivek_jonam: The next method adds entries to the map. Therefore, it requires some kind of synchronization. There is no further synchronization necessary. In particular, there is no synchronization necessary for the individual domains, because the requests are _scheduled_ instead of _synchronized_.

Comment: @nosid I agree with that. But what I asked is we are now synchronizing the next method as a whole, which will be blocking every thread processing every other domain. But instead if we could drill down the locking to each domain level wont it be good?

Comment: @vivek_jonam: No, in this case it doesn't make sense to use fine granular locks. Even if the method `next` will be executed 1000 times per second, each call only requires a few cycles, so that the contention is really low (one thread waiting for another thread).

Answer (score 1):

can you not use `ArrayBlockingQueue or ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (or similar queue structures from `java.util.concurrent`). Add the request to the queue and pull them out at regular intervals?

This is reasonable for small-scale domain names. If your domain set is large,
using map is a better idea. The solution your proposed seems fine. you might need to `concurentHasHmap`,but you would still need to lock individual keys after each request is handled.
The only advantage of using `concurrentHashMap` is that the map itself is not locked, so read operations is fine to do.

Comment: Maintain separate queues for each domain name?